# Calculating the Casimir force in 1+1 dimensions for a real scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, casimir-effect

Let $\phi(x,t)$ be a real scalar field in 1+1 dimension that lives in an interval $x \in [0,L]$. That is, $\phi(0,t)=\phi(L,t)=0$. Now after some calculations for the vacuum energy and using renormalization, I earned the finite term $-\pi/{24L}$. It is said to be Casimir energy. What exactly is the meaning of this energy? And it is also said that there is a force acting on the walls at $x=0, L$(called Casimir force). But the energy $-\pi/{24L}$ is just constant and there  seems to be no source for force acting on the walls. Could anyone please explain what the source of the force is? And also how to calculate the force?

Comment: Force is the derivative of energy (in this case, with respect to $L$).

Comment: Then at $x=0$ the force diverges

Comment: It sure does. So what?

Comment: Infinite force doesn't seem physically plausible to me...

Comment: It is not. But then again, you could say the exact same thing about e.g., the Coulomb force.

Comment: So, the force at $x=L$ is $\pi/{24L^2}$, which is repulsive. And the force at $x=0$ is divergent but also repulsive?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403525/2451